# compression gzip not working (expressjs - compression library)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, compression

I use from [compression library](https://github.com/expressjs/compression) and still not working..
this is my config :

```
const app = express();

app.use(compression());

app.use("/public", express.static(path.join(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../public'))));
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to [this link](https://github.com/expressjs/compression/issues/95#event-850601249) By default, this module does not compress responses that contain already compressed assets, like JPEG images. You can use the filter option to override this behavior if you like.

```
app.use(compression({
  filter: function () { return true; }
}));
```